# Oracle Stored Procedure with Websphere application server 7

Tags: stored-procedures, websphere-7

Each time when i modify a oracle stored proc,i need to restart the was server to pick up the stored proc changes.

Is there any settings which can be used to reload the same in production env.

Comment: Achieved using the following options  **1. In the datasource properties set the statement cache to 0 - no statements will be cached then - this however may have negative impact on performance if you are using lots of prepared and callable statements
2. Try to purge the connection pool for data sources affected by procedure change. 
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21220832
**

Answer (score 0):

You may try to start your server in debugging mode and then , after changing your stored proc, clean build your project directory. But it is always advisable to not to use debug mode in Production Env.. If your stored proc is changing frequently, then you should change your stored proc to more dynamic one.